# how add NSMutableDictionary object to other NSMutableDictionary at position last+1

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSArray With NSMutableDictionary object inside this array like the following .What i want to get an object say at index:2 of this array and add that NSMutableDictionary object from the following array into other NSMutableDictionary already have say five elements at positions 6:

`(
        {
        eventId = 2;
        eventName = "Sweels ";
    },
        {
        eventId = 1;
        eventName = "Lakenge";
    },
        {
        eventId = 23;
        eventName = "Royta";
    }
)`

I am able to get the NSMutableDictionary object and and can extract the key and value and then can add but want to add whole object without extracting the key and values

```
{
    eventId = 23;
    eventName = "Royta";
}
```

Comment: dictionary is not ordered - it's not possible to achievie this using only a dictionary. You'd need to use two structures at once - dictionary and array (possbibly by encapsulating in custom ordereddictionary class).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an NSMutableDictionary object with the keys and values contained in another given dictionary using this initializer:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
```

Example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:extractedDict];
```

If You do not want to create a new NSMutableDictionary Object and just need to add Key/Values to an existing Object then Use this Method:

```
- (void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)keyedValues
```

Example:

```
[newDict setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:extractedDict];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the values as single object than you must do this-

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[myArray addObjectsFromArray:[paramsDictionary allValues]];

NSLog(@"%@",[paramsDictionary allValues]);
```